# How to use backspace in terminal in ubuntu 13.10..?

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I am using ubuntu 13.10.I cant able to use backspace in terminal. While using backspace it just passed through the letters.Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by editing the terminal profile.

1. Go *Profile Preferences*, either by:

   Right-clicking in the terminal window and choosing *Profiles >> Profiles Preferences*

   Or from the menu: *Edit >> Profile Preferences*
2. Go the the compatibility tab
3. Find *Backspace key generates*
4. Select ASCII DEL

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If by "passed through the letters" you mean the cursor goes back over top of the previous character without removing it, then your computer simply can't render the terminal properly. If you type a letter after that, it should replace the letter it was hovering over.

The problem should be resolved by closing (or logging out) of the terminal and opening (or logging back in to) the terminal.

The only other option I can think of is somehow your keyboard layout is incorrect and thinks that the backspace key is the left arrow key.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor has got 2 states. One looks like a box and the other is an under score. It seems the current state of yours is the box. Simply press the **Ins** key (Insert key) in your keyboard and the cursor transforms into a line. It should work as normal.

P.S: The Insert key is a keyboard key located on the majority of all computers that allows text to be inserted. When insert is enabled, the text inserted in a document will not overwrite any other text. However, when disabled, text will be overwritten.